# Dolar to Argentinian Peso convertor with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an American Dollar to Argentinian Peso converter. I am really struggling with the JS because here in Argentina we have various different rates (dolar Blu, Dolar Turista, Dolar Mayorista, and the official dollar rate that is the one the Central Bank imposes). So I need that the amount that the user inputs gets multiplied by different rates.

Here is the JS code I have so far:

```
function convertir() {
    var A = document.getElementById('cantidad').value
    var B = 145
    var C = 95.73
    var D = 157.95
    var E = 90.26
    var F = "0"

    if (A > 0) {
        F = parseInt(A) * parseInt(B)
        document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = F
    }
}
```

The different variables are different exchange rates.

Thanks a lot for your assistance

Comment: Can you describe the expected result, please.

Comment: necesitamos un ejemplo de tu quiera (*we need an example of what you want*)

Comment: I would like to get the result in the HTML in different cattegories " dolar Blue: "result" - Dolar Turista: "result" etc

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting all rates to an array

```
const rates = [145, 95.73, 157.95, 90.26]
```

and receive all results by iterating over this array. 
Assuming initial value is `A`

```
const converted = rates.map(rate => A*rate);
```

Which will result to an array of converted values. See [Map docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for details